# Seo Breadcrumbs in Google showing only 3 and not the correct 3 of our breadcrumb path: how to change?

Tags: seo, google, breadcrumbs

google only shows 3 breadcrumbs in search something like

[image]

Our paths are 4 breadcrumbs deep and the complete string is `https://store.com › Cars › Colors > Blue`

The problem is that for the below query we searched for "Blue Cars" and the breadcrumb shown is not best for CTR

Instead it should be `https://store.com › Cars › Blue` or `https://store.com › Cars > Colors › Blue`

Our JSON LD code is `[{"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"BreadcrumbList","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"item":{"@id":"https:\/\/domain.com\/","name":"Domain"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"item":{"@id":"https:\/\/domain.com\/cars","name":"All cars"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":3,"item":{"@id":"https:\/\/domain.com\/cars\/colors","name":"All Car Colors"}}, ,{"@type":"ListItem","position":4,"item":{"@id":"https:\/\/domain.com\/cars/colors/blue","name":"All Blue cars"}}]}]`

**Question**: How can we change this behavior and is it smart to do.

We could:

1. take first, second and only last breadcrumb : but then we would be solving the problem, only would be be incomplete from a logical perspective
2. Or is there some way to tell Google what is preferred?
3. Do nothing?

Answer (score 1):

You have specified the breadcrumbs correctly but the thing is that blue color is not a category. In my opinion, if it's in last it is more a landing page instead, and google only shows the breadcrumbs of categories like if you add another category after colors, let's assume size,  `https://store.com › Cars › Colors > Big` then the colors will  also become a category and the size will become the landing page, also I have seen that Google only shows three categories in bread crumbs if 4th position is performed as a landing page, so its better if use it like this, `https://store.com › Cars › blue > blue cars`

Another Solution of this is that use the HTML schema instead of json it will then show complete URL as breadcrumbs properly:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
<a itemprop="url" href='http://allrecipes.co.uk/recipes/?o_is=RD_Breadcrumb'><span itemprop="title">Recipes</span></a>
</li><li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a itemprop="url" href='http://allrecipes.co.uk/recipes/recipe-type.aspx?o_is=RD_Breadcrumb'>
<span itemprop="title">Dish type</span></a></li>
<li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a itemprop="url" href='http://allrecipes.co.uk/recipes/cake-recipes.aspx?o_is=RD_Breadcrumb'><span itemprop="title">Cake</span></a></li><li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
<a itemprop="url" href='http://allrecipes.co.uk/recipes/tag-2527/sponge-cake-recipes.aspx?o_is=RD_Breadcrumb'>
<span itemprop="title">Sponge cake</span></a></li>
<li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
<a itemprop="url" href='http://allrecipes.co.uk/recipes/tag-6551/easy-sponge-cake-recipes.aspx?o_is=RD_Breadcrumb'><span itemprop="title">Easy sponge cake</span></a></li>    </ul>
```